# Ajax request to my Rails app : 301 Moved permanently

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am sending a post  request to my Rails app :

```
 $.ajax 
  url: "/" + locale + "/administration/dashboards/remove_tag_named.json"
  type: "POST"
  dataType: "json",
  contentType: "json"
  data: {"tag_name": "bingo" }
  success: (result) ->
    .....
```

I can see the post in the console , but I don't get the success back, after the post I see a lot of GET request listed

```
[19:37:00.052] POST http://localhost:3000/fr/administration/dashboards/remove_tag_named.json [HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently 42ms]
Started GET "/fr/administration%2Fdashboards%2Fremove_tag_named.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-01-16 19:32:31 +0100
Started GET "/fr/administration%2Fdashboards%2Fremove_tag_named.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-01-16 19:32:31 +0100
....
```

in my rails app , I have

```
  respond_to :html, :json
  .....
  def remove_tag_named
    # should remove the tag from the table
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to administration_dashboards_url, notice: t(:tag_deleted) }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

what could be wrong ?  is it the jQuery ajax request or the Rails response ?
if I try to insert a debugger in my Rails action, nothing happen ..

```
  I have checked my routes and it's ok :

    remove_tag_named_administration_dashboards_fr POST /fr/administration/console/remove_tag_named(.:format)    administration/dashboards#remove_tag_named {:locale=>"fr"}

   remove_tag_named_administration_dashboards_en POST /en/administration/dashboards/remove_tag_named(.:format) administration/dashboards#remove_tag_named {:locale=>"en"}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is the ajax response. You're not sending anything other than a 204 status code.

```
format.json { head :no_content }
```

Also you may want that *remove_tag_named* method to have an error condition.

```
def remove_tag_named
  @tag = # get tag properly
  respond_to do |format|
    if @tag.destroy
      format.html { redirect_to administration_dashboards_url, notice: t(:tag_deleted) }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    else
      format.html { # handle error condition }
      format.json { # return error info }
    end
end
```

Comment: thanks , is there any reason I cannot insert a debugger statement
  def remove_tag_named
    debugger

seems not to be take in account

Comment: i'm not to familiar with debugger. i gave up on it when it broke with 1.9. I usually use the pry REPL for debugging. I know that a binding.pry inserted inline will work. Also check out the better errors gem which will give you a more useful error stack trace. you can even add a REPL if you want. :)